# I used function and it is working well, but for $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); doesn't working

Tags: mysql, pdo

Good day, please help me to solve issue for (`$userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`)

```
public function doLogin($uname,$umail,$upass)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT acctID, username, email, password FROM tbl_user WHERE username=:uname OR email=:umail ");
        $stmt->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':umail'=>$umail));
        $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        if($stmt->rowCount() == 0)
        {
            if(password_verify($upass, $userRow['password']))
            {
                $_SESSION['user_session'] = $userRow['acctID'];
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: For $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETH_ASSOC); it return fale.
Please help me to solve it.

Comment: if fetch() returns false then there are no (more) data available.

Comment: I wrote a canonical example for the task, [Authenticating a user using PDO and password_verify()](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/password_hash). Please refer for the more optimal code. As of the $userRow equal to false it means that your query found no rows